# Scale invariant boundary condition (BC) and topological operators

Tags: conformal-field-theory, boundary-conditions

I'm going over the notes of D.S. Duffin at Tasi on Conformal Bootstrap ([arXiv:1602.07982](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.07982)) and I can't seem to understand something rather fundamental.

In order to derive the restriction imposed on a two point function in a CFT he argues that

> "In a scale-invariant theory with scale-invariant boundary conditions, the simultaneous action of $D$ (dilatation charge) on all operators in a correlator must vanish. Moving $D$ to the boundary gives zero."

I can understand the result in terms of a quantization scheme where we impose that the vacuum of the theory is scale invariant, but I find it hard to understand it in this language.

Comment: "I can understand the result in terms of a quantization scheme where we impose that the vacuum of the theory is scale invariant" that's the entire point, no?

Comment: I guess what I mean is that I am looking for an explanation that only uses the Ward Identity and the path integral without actually introducing a Hilbert Space. 
P.S. if you look at the notes of DSD, the equation (46) is the quantization scheme I was reffering to in the post.